In Ubuntu 22.04 | Kubernetes Connection Refused
kubectl get pods -o wide | kubectl get nodes
Error from server (Timeout): the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get pods)
API Server

Controller Manager
scheduler
Continuously restarting Pods
